# How to match any letter in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return rows where certain fields follow a particular pattern such as whether a particular character in a string is a letter or number. To test it out, I want to return fields where the first letter is any letter. I used this code.

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE `customerfirstname` like '[a-z]%';
```

It returns nothing. So I would think that the criteria is the first character is a letter and then any following characters do not matter.
The following code works, but limits rows where the first character is an a.

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE `customerfirstname` like 'a%';
```

Am I not understanding pattern matching? Isn't it [a-z] or [A-Z] or [0-9] for any letter or number?
Also if I wanted to run this test on the second character in a string, wouldn't I use

```
SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE `customerfirstname` like '_[a-z]%'
```

This is for SQL and MySQL. I am doing this in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use regular expressions:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM sales s
WHERE s.customerfirstname REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]';
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with a regular expression.

```
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(customerfirstname, '^[[:alpha:]]');
```

`^` denotes the start of the string, while the `[:alpha]` character class matches any alphabetic character.

Just in case, here are a few others character classes that you may find useful :

- `alnum` : dlphanumeric characters
- `digit`:  digit characters
- `lower` : lowercase alphabetic characters
- `upper`:  uppercase alphabetic characters

See [the mysql regexp docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) for many more...